# unable to create azure managed application - Failed to process changes during VSTS operation for offe

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Hi I have an Azure managed application offer with two plans. I am getting errors when I try to publish the offer. After uploading the app.zip file (that contains maintemplate.json and createUIdef.json) and when I hit save, review, and publish, it fails at the package provisioning stage with the below error message.

> Failed. Operation failed, exception: Failed to process changes during VSTS operation for offer 'xxxx plan '

I can deploy the maintemplate.json ARM template, no problem there, and template verification shows no errors. It doesn't show me any additional details, and what is causing this?

Comment: it turns out that the secret value we added 'SAStoken' is not allowed.  We need to access file stored in a storage account using URI with Sas token.  From what I understand, we have to use the key vault to retrieve it using nested ARM template but not sure how can I do that using bicep.